# How to decrypt using the openssl API's with C/LINUX -- EVP_DecryptFinal_ex

Tags: encryption, openssl

Below works fine for encrypt and decrypt using the passphrase.

openssl aes-256-cbc -in plaintext_file.txt -out encrypted_file.enc -pass pass:111111
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -in encrypted_file.enc -out decrypted_file.txt -pass pass:111111

The same I am trying to decrypt using openssl API's as pasted in the below URL.

full code at https://pastebin.com/cthff0Pd

```
if (1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, outBuf, &decryptedLen)) 
{
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        perror("Error finalizing decryption");
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
        fclose(inFile);
        fclose(outFile);
        return 1;
}
```

When I execute the same, The decrypted context is not a plain text file but with some garbeld values.

I tried to check the error log given by the openssl API's but not with much clue.

I belive some of the padding or some changes still needs to be done to make it work fine.

Comment: In the code, the salt is incorrectly not taken into account during key derivation. The salt is to be determined from the encrypted data, which consists of the concatenation of the prefix `Salted__` plus 8 bytes salt plus the *actual* ciphertext. Also bear in mind that only the *actual* ciphertext (and not the *concatenated* data) must be decrypted during the subsequent decryption. In addition, the padding is incorrectly disabled in the code.